# 2 AJAX functions on one page - Follow/Unfollow button with PHP - not working

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I want to have a Follow/Unfollow button on a page.

The user clicks Follow and this passes the parameter 'artist' to the PHP script, updates a db and the button then says Unfollow.

When the user clicks Unfollow, this passes the parameter 'artist'  to the same PHP script and this then updates a db via PHP and then button then says Follow.

I can get the Follow to change to Unfollow but cannot get Unfollow to change to Follow.

My code is as follows:

> **index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function followArtist(str)
        {
        if (str=="")
          {
          document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML="";
          return;
          } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/follow.php?artist=<?php echo $artist; ?>"+str+"&follow=y",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
        </script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        function unfollowArtist(str)
        {
        if (str=="")
          {
          document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML="";
          return;
          } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML=XMLHTTPlhttp.responseText;

            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/follow.php?artist=<?php echo $artist; ?>"+str+"&follow=n",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
        </script>


    <!--Follow button for user to click-->          
<div class="follow_text" id="artist">
<h1><a href="javascript:void(0)"    onclick="followArtist(this.value)">Follow artist</a></h1>
            </div>
```

> **follow.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['follow']))
    {
        $follow = $_GET['follow'];
        if($follow=='y')
            {
                $artist = $_GET['artist'];
                #############do a database action
                ?>
                <h1><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="unfollowArtist(this.value)">Unfollow artist</a></h1>

            <?php
            }
        else
            {
                $artist = $_GET['artist'];
                #############do a database action
                ?>
                <h1><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="followArtist(this.value)">Follow artist</a></h1>

            <?php
            }

    }
```

?>

Any ideas why this is not working?

You can see a live version of the script at http://soundshelter.net/release.php?id=421928

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `this.value` doesn't work on `a` tags..might want to correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the second xmlhttp object which throws error.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function unfollowArtist(str)
            {
            if (str=="")
              {
              document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML="";
              return;
              } 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp2=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp2=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
           xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp2.readyState==4 && xmlhttp2.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML=xmlhttp2.responseText;

                }
              }
           xmlhttp2.open("GET","/follow.php?artist=<?php echo $artist; ?>"+str+"&follow=n",true);
           xmlhttp2.send();
            }
            </script>


        <!--Follow button for user to click-->          
    <div class="follow_text" id="artist">
    <h1><a href="javascript:void(0)"    onclick="followArtist(this.value)">Follow artist</a></h1>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second

```
<h1><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="followArtist(this.value)">Unfollow artist</a></h1>
```

shoud be Follow artist

Comment: Thanks for that, changed! Unfortunately it hasn't changed any of the workings. Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: XMLHTTPlhttp in unfollowArtist(str) function is undefined it should be replaced with xmlhttp